# SQL - Select query to get purchase orders that have two or more products from different product lines

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, having

I'm wondering what I can do to rework/improve this query (it takes too long to run).

Some background info:
Order ID => 'id'
Purchase ID => 'pid'
"Table" is a table of purchase lines, the id is the id of an order, and orders can have multiple lines. For example, there can be three lines with id 1, having various purchase ids, so:

id | pid
1  |  3
1  |  3
1  |  46

The purpose of the query is to find orders that have purchases from multiple product lines, such as 1, 21, 31, 41 and 2, 22, 32, 42.

Query below is what I came up with, but it runs very slowly from all the sub-queries, is it possible to optimize this query or get the same results with a different, faster query?

```
SELECT a.id
FROM Table AS a
GROUP BY a.id
HAVING (
  CAST( CASE WHEN EXISTS (SELECT NULL FROM Table WHERE pid IN ('1', '21', '31', '41') AND id = a.id ) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS INT) +
  CAST( CASE WHEN EXISTS (SELECT NULL FROM Table WHERE pid IN ('2', '22', '32', '42') AND id = a.id ) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS INT) +
  CAST( CASE WHEN EXISTS (SELECT NULL FROM Table WHERE pid IN ('3', '23', '33', '43') AND id  = a.id ) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS INT) +
  CAST( CASE WHEN EXISTS (SELECT NULL FROM Table WHERE pid IN ('4', '24', '34', '44') AND id = a.id ) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS INT) +
  CAST( CASE WHEN EXISTS (SELECT NULL FROM Table WHERE pid IN ('5', '25', '35', '45') AND id = a.id ) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS INT) +
  CAST( CASE WHEN EXISTS (SELECT NULL FROM Table WHERE pid IN ('6', '26', '36', '46') AND id = a.id ) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS INT) +
  CAST( CASE WHEN EXISTS (SELECT NULL FROM Table WHERE pid  IN ('7', '27', '37', '47') AND id = a.id ) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS INT) +
  CAST( CASE WHEN EXISTS (SELECT NULL FROM Table WHERE pid IN ('8', '28', '38', '48') AND id = a.id ) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS INT)
) > 1
```

EDIT:

Final working query (is 97% faster than previous):

```
SELECT y.Id
FROM (SELECT  x.Id,
              x.productLine
FROM ( SELECT a.id,
    CASE 
        WHEN a.pid IN ('1', '21', '31', '41') THEN 1
        WHEN a.pid IN ('2', '22', '32', '42') THEN 2
        WHEN a.pid IN ('3', '23', '33', '43') THEN 3
        WHEN a.pid IN ('4', '24', '34', '44') THEN 4
        WHEN a.pid IN ('5', '25', '35', '45') THEN 5
        WHEN a.pid IN ('6', '26', '36', '46') THEN 6
        WHEN a.pid IN ('7', '27', '37', '47') THEN 7
        WHEN a.pid IN ('8', '28', '38', '48') THEN 8
        ELSE 9 
    END AS productLine
    FROM Table AS a
    WHERE a.pid IN ('1', '21', '31', '41','2', '22', '32', '42','3', '23', '33', '43','4', '24', '34', '44','5', '25', '35', '45','6', '26', '36', '46','7', '27', '37', '47','8', '28', '38', '48')
) AS x
GROUP BY x.Id, x.productLine
) AS y
GROUP BY y.Id
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
```

Comment: orders, purchase lines, product lines... where are they? There are only two columns.

Comment: Orders are in "Table" by "id", so order #1 is all the order lines from "Table" with an id of 1 Order IDs are NOT unique in "Table". Purchase lines are each individual line in "Table", they will have an order ID and a purchase ID, such as order id 1, purchase id 43. Product lines are non-database related, arbitrary groupings of products with specific IDs, such as (1,21,31,41) or (8,28,38,48).  PS: I'm not happy with the way this was setup, but I am in no position to change it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I understand Your problem this query should meet your request:

```
SELECT  x.Id
FROM    ( SELECT    a.Id ,
                    CAST(a.pid AS INT) % 10 AS pid
          FROM      [Table] AS a
          GROUP BY  a.Id ,
                    CAST(a.pid AS INT) % 10
        ) x
GROUP BY x.Id
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
```

After taking into account new assumptions query should look like:

```
SELECT y.Id
(SELECT  x.Id,
        x.pid
FROM    ( SELECT a.id,
        CASE WHEN a.pid IN ('1', '21', '31', '41') THEN 1
        WHEN a.pid IN ('2', '22', '32', '42') THEN 2
        WHEN a.pid IN ('3', '23', '33', '43') THEN 3
        WHEN a.pid IN ('4', '24', '34', '44') THEN 4
        WHEN a.pid IN ('5', '25', '35', '45') THEN 5
        WHEN a.pid IN ('6', '26', '36', '46') THEN 6
        WHEN a.pid IN ('7', '27', '37', '47') THEN 7
        WHEN a.pid IN ('8', '28', '38', '48') THEN 8
        ELSE 9 END AS productLine
        FROM Table AS a
        ) x
GROUP BY x.Id, x.pid) y
GROUP BY y.Id
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
```

Comment: Creative, but the product lineups (groups?) are, for example: 1, 21, 31, 41, and this query is pulling orders with 1 and 41, I'm trying to have it pull orders with only two or more product groups: for example, pull an order with 1, 41, 22, but not 1, 41, 21.

Comment: Ok, a few changes that I had to make to make this run- Adding a "FROM" after SELECT y.Id at the start of line 2, and changing x.pid to x.productLine on lines 3 and 16. Finally, I had to add WHERE a.pid IN ('1', '21', '31', '41', '2'. . . etc) with all pid's inbetween line 15 and 14, after FROM Table AS a, due to the fact there were some pid's that were not a part of a product lineup (group). HOWEVER!!! After all this, the query runs an astonishing 97% faster than what I had previously, many many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Althoug I really like Rafał's solution as it gives numbers to the groups, I thought of another, little simplier solution, but was unable to test it earlier.

```
SELECT distinct(id) FROM store a
WHERE 4 = (
    SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT(pid)) 
    FROM store
    where (id = a.id AND (
        pid in (1, 21, 31, 41)  OR 
        pid in (2, 22, 32, 42)
        )
    )
)
```